# cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy' when I import Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

When I try to import `Seaborn` I got this error

'cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy'

And I am using '1.24.1' version of `numpy`

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Seaborn have you installed?

Comment: @Daweo From ANACONDA NAVIGATOR, it says 0.10.1

Comment: [Release history](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/#history) suggest that 0.10.1 was released in April 2020 and newest version is 0.12.2, please try installing latest version and test what would happen if you then try import it.

Comment: @Daweo I just installed all the modules and now I got `500:Internal Server Error` :(

Comment: This is HTTP error code, this suggest that during `import seaborn` there is some HTTP request done, this is surprising for me, as I did not expect seaborn working to impinge at access to network.

Comment: @Daweo Oh I mean now I just can't use Jupyter notebook, when I try to open a notebook, it says `500:Internal Server Error`.. Im trying to upgrade other modules now :( thank you for the advice tho